# Google Maps directions throws error from URL of coordinate pairs

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-urls

A direct link to Google Maps Directions, where the destination is provided as a coordinate pair, can be created with the following URL:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir//37.78133194213231,-122.43221998214722

[directions](https://www.google.com/maps/dir//37.78133194213231,-122.43221998214722)

However, when opening the link to the Google Maps app on mobile devices such as iOS, this throws an "unsupported link" error every time, whether accessed through Safari or Chrome.

Is there a workaround for this problem ([documented here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/4lbDXSQF73k)) ?  Please note that a URL containing **both** origin and destination will throw the same error.

Comment: Have you tried an official [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action), i.e. sending `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=37.78133194213231,-122.43221998214722` instead of your's?

Comment: Using the official Google Maps URLs produces the same error, unfortunately.  Try it.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the app. I'd suggest sending them feedback as described in https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094045?hl=en&ref_topic=3093612&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=1